# How do you fix this 'unlabeled value' error?

Tags: circuit-design, ltspice, simulation

I'm really new at this and I can't understand what value is not labeled here.

[image]

Comment: It looks like "In" is floating so, try and connect it to a signal source or even ground to see if the error changes.

Comment: Thank you, it fixed that, but now it gives me the same error in b&v3...

Comment: Something looks mucked up in your installation. You should not need the .inc line for the OP07.  Not sure the significance of the silcrow §.

Comment: Looks to me like you used the wrong symbol for the voltage sources. You used `bv` instead of `voltage` and you are using `bv` incorrectly by editing several of its parameter fields. Just use `voltage` instead.